# How do I remove some unwanted x ticks in PGFPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

I am not sure where I am doing wrong, but in the plot I should not have two 32, two 64 and two 128 on the x-axis. Here is a minimum working example; I would appreciate any assistance.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{How do systems perform...}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=XX Graph  (42M vertices; 1.46B edges; size 12.5GB),
    width = 11cm,
    height = 6cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar = 1pt,% configures `bar shift'
    bar width=10pt,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 2500,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    legend style = {%
      at = {(0.5,-0.3)},
      anchor = north,
      legend columns = -1},
    ylabel = {Time (in sec)},
    xlabel = {Scale},
    symbolic x coords = {16,32,64,128},
    ytick = {0,500,1000,1500,2000},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ]
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 260.00) (32, 168.33) (64, 110.67) (128, 224.00) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 575.50) (32, 278.80) (64, 259.25) (128, 233.69) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 597.75) (32, 584.64) (64, 260.33) (128, 398.00) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 411.00) (32, 373.00) (64, 143.00) (128, 168.33) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 181) (32, 879.25) (64, 1200.67) (128, 1934) };
        \small{\legend{A,B,C ,D ,E}}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add `xtick=data` to avoid this behavior.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=XX Graph  (42M vertices; 1.46B edges; size 12.5GB),
            width=11cm,
            height=6cm,
            major x tick style=transparent,
            ybar=1pt,% configures `bar shift'
            bar width=10pt,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2500,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.3)},
                anchor=north,
                legend columns=-1},
            ylabel={Time (in sec)},
            xlabel={Scale},
            ytick={0,500,1000,1500,2000},
            scaled y ticks=false,
            symbolic x coords = {16,32,64,128},
        % this was the missing line
            xtick=data,
            % this is that the bars are not cutted at the end of the axis
            enlarge x limits={0.2},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 260.00) (32, 168.33) (64, 110.67) (128, 224.00) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 575.50) (32, 278.80) (64, 259.25) (128, 233.69) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 597.75) (32, 584.64) (64, 260.33) (128, 398.00) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 411.00) (32, 373.00) (64, 143.00) (128, 168.33) };
            \addplot coordinates {(16, 181.00) (32, 879.25) (64, 1200.67) (128, 1934) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]